# how to prove positive definite complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

In order to prove that that a quadratic function is convex: $x^HAx$ , $A$ needs to be positive semi definite. Where $A= \Phi^H \Phi$ and $\Phi$ is a n×k matrix with possibly k linearly independent columns. How to prove that A is positive semi definite?

Comment: $\Phi$ is a complex matrix $\in C$

Answer (score 1):

$A^*A=B$ if and only if $B$ is positive semi-definite.

$\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=||Ax||^2\ge 0$ for all $x\in {\mathbb{C}}^n$

Comment: you are right, but I want to prove it

Comment: As long as we are dealing with complex numbers, wouldn't it be: $ \langle Ax,Ax \rangle = (Ax)^H(Ax)$?. The complex inner product $(Ax)^H(Ax)$ doesn't necessarily equals $\|Ax\|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\overline{z} z\geq 0$$ for any complex number $z.$

$$x^H A x= x^H{\Phi^H}\Phi x = {(\Phi x)}^H {\Phi x}=\overline{\Phi x} \Phi x.$$

Comment: Thanks for the Hint. What if $X$ is a matrix instead of a vector then how it will effect the $\geqslant 0$ condition ?

Comment: If $X$ is a matrix, then consists of vectors. For each of them is valid the positivity of the result. But the resulting object will not be a scalar, and I wonder in what sense would be understood $\geq 0.$

Comment: Well what I am thinking is that , the result depends upon the semidefinite properties of matrix $A = \Phi^H\Phi$. The particular case I am working on is, where $\Phi$ is a Gaussian matrix. One way to go forward is to look for the positivity of the Eigen-values. If each of the Eigen-value is $\geqslant 0$ then may be we can say that  $B = X^H\Phi^H\Phi X$ is positive /semi positive definite. 

I am not sure if this is the right direction.